# Golang Equivalent to list accounts on node - web3.eth.Accounts()

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, accounts, golang

Does anyone know if its possible to get a list of the accounts on a node using golang, after Dialing to the node, basic PoC would be assuming the accounts are already unlocked via the CLI

Basically looking for the same functionality as `web3.eth.Accounts()` or to list the account addresses on a remote geth node that are already unlocked via the CLI

Comment: Could you clarify/define "dialling into the node"?

Comment: To connect to a node in go you use the ```ethclient.Dial()```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to interact with the keystore, this is a package i wrote for interacting with keystore function "GetAllKeys" will list all the accounts.
package keystore

```
import (
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
)

type KeyStore struct {
    Handle *keystore.KeyStore
}

func SetUpKeyStore(kp string) *KeyStore {
    ks := &KeyStore{}
    ks.Handle = keystore.NewKeyStore(kp, keystore.LightScryptN, keystore.LightScryptP)
    return ks
}

func (ks *KeyStore) CreateNewKeys(password string) accounts.Account {
    account, err := ks.Handle.NewAccount(password)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    return account
}

func (ks *KeyStore) GetKeysByAddress(address string) accounts.Account {

    var account accounts.Account
    var err error
    if ks.Handle.HasAddress(common.HexToAddress(address)) {
        if account, err = ks.Handle.Find(accounts.Account{Address: common.HexToAddress(address)}); err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }
    }
    return account
}

func (ks *KeyStore) GetAllKeys() []accounts.Account {

    return ks.Handle.Accounts() 
}
```

Comment: What is the implementation here? `setupKeyStore(string)`, what string? Then pass `*keystore` to `GetAllKeys`?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing my own implementation doing a post request to the node, pretty much what web3 does under the hook with RPC/WS endpoints

Comment: any more details on POST request or link to doc/rpc methods?